# NumberFormatException.forInputString"2D array"

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code

```
String[][] Matrix=new String[row][col];//I initialized this string array
int[][] F = new int[row][col];
```

But when I run

```
F[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(Matrix[0][0]);
```

But this gives me an error:

```
NumberFormatException.forInputString"2D array"
```

How can I solve this problem?

[Edit] Sory all, I missitated, actually,  The array itself in quotes.

Comment: `"2D array"` is not an integer

Comment: Matrix is as follows;0 1 2 5 0 4
2 2 2 4 0 0
3 1 0 1 1 1
3 1 2 0 2 5
0 0 5 0 1 1

Comment: 1) Your `Matrix` contains an element at `[0][0]` which says: `"2D array"`. Which isn't a number. 2) Follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) (`FirstWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, and `ALL_UPPERCASE_CONSTANT`), this will make your code easier to read for you and us. If this doesn't help, post a valid [mcve] that demonstrates your problem

Comment: [Your code runs just fine if you put integers in your matrix](http://ideone.com/9uDyob) (which is the only thing that makes sense if you want to do `parseInt`). Post a [mcve] which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your matrix into your question with better formatting.  It's impossible to tell which elements are which.

Comment: That's because you haven't filled the `Matrix` with any value! But IDK why others think that you can't!

Answer (score 0):

you have a row x col matrix of nulls, ergo this is invalid

```
Integer.parseInt(Matrix[0][0]);
```

since is the same as

```
Integer.parseInt(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Java Documentation

> **NumberFormatException** is thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

Please check whether your 2D Array of String **i.e Matrix** contains valid Integer values or not else you will get this exception.